# Deployed SSIS package fails when running from a SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

Let me know what additional info would help. I have an SSIS package that Imports a csv file to SQL Server and moves that csv into a subfolder of the folder where the csv resides. I can run the package from the Integration Services Catalog with no problem, but when running from the Agent Job it says it can't read the .csv file and I've tried different versions of the file. I tried recreating the job also. No luck. Also the C# script task is not moving the csv to the archive folder even when I run the package from the ISC. The agent error tells me to look at the Execution of the package which says basically it can't open the csv.

Comment: Sounds like NTFS permissions. Check the user account agent is running under.

Comment: Says it is using AD/bcampbell which is me

Comment: So bcampbell clicks run package via SSMS and it works. Do you run that from a local desktop that connects to Server1 or do you remote into Server1 and run the package from there? When the job runs, does it run as the SQL Agent account or has a credentialed user been established and that is associated to the job? What is the account that is being used - domain or local computer account? Is the network file identified by a UNC path (\\server\share\file1.csv) or a mounted drive (M:\file1.csv)

Comment: I use my SSMS from my local machine and the UNC Path for the network file is \\10.1.30.29\ssis\   the Agent runs with AD\bcampbell... when I run the package from my local Visual Studio the file moves like it should and the table gets updated as expected.

Comment: I connect to the \\10.1.30.29\ server where SQL Server is hosted along with the csv file... and I connect onto this server rather than remoting in.